# If $P(x)$ is a polynomial over the Real Field such that for an integer $k$, $P(k)$ is an integer, then show that $n!P(x)$ is an integer polynomial

Tags: polynomials

> **Statement:**
>
> If $\mathcal{P(x)} \in \mathbb{R}[x] \ni~ \forall~ k\in\mathbb{Z}, \mathcal{P(k)}\in \mathbb{Z}$, then show that $n!\mathcal{P(x)}$ is an integer polynomial.

---

I have the following question regarding the question:

1) The question doesn't seem complete for some reason. Isn't it that $\exists$ particular $p$ such that for any $n\geq p, ~n!\mathcal{P(x)} \in \mathbb{Z}$?

---

I tried proving the statement. But it was quite unsuccessful. I tried to construct another polynomial $\mathcal{Q(x)}$ with rational coefficients so as to show that both are equal. But that wasn't going the way I wished. And I wasn't getting the $n!$. Please check Point $1$ above as well.

Comment: You are right, it should say $\exists n$ . [Of course if $n!P(x)$ is an integer polynomial for some $n$, then it is also true for all greater $n$.]  Or maybe it should say specifically that $n$ is the degree of $P(x)$.

Comment: @GEdgar Exactly. It's not possible for any random $n$.

Comment: You are probably expected to show this when $n=\deg P(x)$. It goes by induction on $n$. For the inductive step show that the difference $\Delta P(x):=P(x+1)-P(x)$ has degree $n-1$ and also maps integers to integers (and a bit more). We have handled this earlier. Gimme a minute.